# How to implement "didSelectButtonInCellAtIndexPath:" in Objective-C and Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I am familiar with 'UITableViewDelegate'.

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is of power.

How to implement "tableView: didSelectButtonInCellAtIndexPath: " , in Objective-C exactly, also great in Swift.

as the following picture:

[image: pic]

When the button in red circle is clicked , I use a custom UITableViewCell delegate.

So how to upgrade the UITableViewCell delegate to a custom UITableView delegate, to handle the event elegantly.

Comment: Just handle it in the button action on `.touchUpInside`. You do not want to handle it in `didSelect` because there are multiple buttons there.

Comment: If could , the logic is unified and more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple, and actually there are several ways to achieve what you want:

1. Use code blocks. You can have code block as a handler of a button selection like `var buttonSelectionHandler: ((_ index: IndexPath?) -> ())?` and call this on your button's selector. The parameter `index` of the block you can use to indicate which cell is responsible for the action, and don't forget, you should store index path on `cellForRowAtIndex` of `UITableViewDataSource` and have proper property on custom cell.
2. Create custom protocol that has function like you said in the question in the protocol, make your view controller, or view model or any other thing you use as a `UITableViewDataSource` to confirm to that protocol, add property that's type of the that protocol, assign implementing object to the property, and call the method whenever button is selected.

There are some other ways also, but I think this would be enough to solve your issue. Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to explore the tableView a little more under the hood.  Your solution is very common and nice. Prefer a custom  `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.  Build  a connection between cell and viewController inherently through tableView

Answer (score 1):

Rather than **Delegate** I prefer to use a **Block(Objective-C)** or **Closure(Swift)**

These are the example How elegantly actions on buttons can be managed easily also if need to update cell then this can also be easily handled no need to refresh whole tableview and all.

**In Objective-C :**

CustomTableViewCell.h

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^ButtonTapAction)(CustomTableViewCell *aCell);
```

CustomTableViewCell.m

```
//Method assign to that button
- (IBAction)arrowButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    if (self.ButtonTapAction) {
        self.ButtonTapAction(self);
    }
}
```

cell Used in tableview cellForRowAtIndexpath:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        cell.arrowButtonTapAction = ^(CustomTableViewCell *aCell){
            // Do Whatever you want to do on the button click
        };
```

By Using this code you dont need to reload Cell.

**In Swift :**

CustomTableCell.swift

```
typealias  ButtonHandler = (_ aCell:CustomTableCell) -> Void
var buttonClickHandler:ButtonHandler? = nil

@IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        if buttonClickHandler != nil {
            self.buttonClickHandler!(self)
        } 
    }
```

cell Used in tableview cellForRowAtIndexpath:

```
cell.buttonClickHandler = { aCell in
      // Do Whatever you want to do on the button click
}
```

By Using this code you dont need to reload Cell. Also No Need to maintain its indexpath and all stuff just update whatever you want to do or needed any action on button just write in cellForIndexpath that set.

Above is For A single button click in Row. For selecting a whole row you can implement the **DidSelectRow Delegate**